# How can I check if my server is using ssl 3?

Tags: security, ssl, ubuntu-12.04

How can I check if my server is using ssl 3?

When I run openssl version command I get this.

OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012

Thanks.

Comment: OpenSSL is a library, it won't give you a clue on how it's used by your web server.

Comment: Qualys provides a pretty good only SSL  diagnostic service here : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 1):

What server are you talking about?
If it's Apache or any other web-server you may use curl:

```
curl -v3 https://yourwebsite.com
```

This will force curl to use SSLv3. If request succeeds then server supports SSLv3.

Comment: Its apache! Thank you for your help. I get the following result with curl

curl -v3 https://www.xxxxxx.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.xxxxxx.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to www.xxxxxx.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* SSL 3.0 connection using SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
* Server certificate: www.xxxxxx.com
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
* Server certificate: AddTrust External CA Root
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: www.xxxx